# Compile Error - End with

Tags: excel, compilation, vba

So with this code I keep getting a Compile Error End with- How am I able to fix this? This works in all of my other files but not this one. This is basically taking a smiley face icon and updating the color to red or green based on the cells its looking at.

```
    Sub UpdateSmileys()

    'CUSTOMER COMPLAINTS


    If Sheets("Data").Range("T2").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T3").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 133")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 133")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid


    'INTERNAL PPM

    If Sheets("Data").Range("T4").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T5").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 170")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 170")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid


    'EXTERNAL PPM

    If Sheets("Data").Range("T6").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T7").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 120")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 120")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid


  '8D OPEN/CLOSED BY CUSTOMER

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T8").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T9").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 116")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 116")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid




    'SUPPLIER QUALITY DISRUPTIONS

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T10").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T11").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 127")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 127")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid


    'TOTAL QUALITY COSTS

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T12").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T13").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 157")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 157")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid




    'WARRANTY RETURNS

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T14").Value <= Sheets("Data").Range("T15").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 117")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 117")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid

    'DEPARTMENT TRAINING

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T16").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T17").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 128")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 128")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid

    'LP AUDITS

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T3").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T4").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 131")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 131")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid



    'SUPPLIER QUALITY AUDITS

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T24").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T25").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 125")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 125")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid


    'EMPLOYEE MORALE

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T26").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T27").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 129")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 129")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid

    'INTERNAL 8D COMPLETED

   If Sheets("Data").Range("T18").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T19").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 158")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 158")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid

    'INTERNAL DEPARTMENT AUDITS


   If Sheets("Data").Range("T20").Value >= Sheets("Data").Range("T21").Value Then
      Sheets("KPIs").Select
      ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 118")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.04653
   Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 118")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid




    End Sub
```

Comment: You have a lot of `With` blocks without the `End With`.  You need to tell vba when to stop using the `With`.

Comment: If you look at the indentation of your code, you can tell **exactly** where the missing `End With` should go. I count 13 places with a quick scroll through without even looking closely. Learn to read your code, not just copy/paste or pound on the keys.

Comment: Now I get a Block If without End If. I assume this means the same thing and I need to go tell it to `End If`

Comment: We're not going to teach you step by step how to code. Find a VBA tutorial and read the section on IF and WITH to learn how they work.

Comment: But wait...that exact code works in other files, without errors? How so? AFAIK `End If`/`End With` isn't optional ever.

Comment: I guess when I copied and pasted it over and redid it for the different charts I forgot to copy the `End If` and `End With`. Its been a rough week of updating charts and management cockpits - made some rookie mistakes. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above: don't just copy and paste the code but rather start reading it and try to understand it. The following will certainly help you in this case: http://homeandlearn.org/if_statements.html AND http://homeandlearn.org/with_end_with.html But I very much encourage you reading all of the parts / sections on this site. This is a very easy and basic VBA course to get you going. If you don't understand a key-word (the bluish words) then highlight it with the cursor and press `F1` and read some more.